# Spotify Plugin Opening up Spotify

Tags: wordpress, spotify

Ive tried pasting the embed code directly from spotify and into my php file. Once I hit play on the iframe it opens up Spotify and plays from there. I want the music to play directly from the webpage and not in Spotify.

I don't have a lot of experience in WordPress/php, so I'm not sure where to start in terms of modification of the code.

Comment: I've seen on sites that have Spotify playlists that you can choose to play the songs and they play directly off of the site. However I have copied and pasted the embed code directly from Spotify into my php file and when I hit play it opens Spotify on my computer and plays the music from my app

Comment: Question was edited @KirkBeard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of the Spotify Play Button.

> When a logged-in Spotify user clicks the button, the music will start
>   playing in the Spotify player. If the user is not logged into their
>   Spotify account, the Spotify Play Button will play a 30-second audio
>   preview of the music, and they will be prompted to login or sign up.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/).

There is currently no way to get full track playback from Spotify directly in the browser. With the Web API, you can either play 30 second clips (part of the track object [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#track-object-simplified)) or control Spotify connect, which will start playback in a Spotify player (documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-connect-endpoint-reference/)).